# how to check If checkbox is checked or not laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

I want to show a button if checkbox gets checked and if not checked button will not appear in laravel 5.4. How can I do this.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox">
```

In front-end you can check using jQuery

```
if ($('#checkbox').is(':checked')){
   //
}
```

In back-end you can check using:

```
if (isset($request->checkbox) {
     //
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by using jquery

```
$('#checkbox').change(function(){
        if($('#checkbox').is(':checked')){
    console.log("asdad");
        $('#button').css('display','inline');
    }else{
        $('#button').css('display','none');
    }
})
```

Comment: is there a way to do it in laravel itself. Like If I can submit form if checkbox gets checked.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can verify if checkbox is checked in BackEnd

```
if($request['checkBoxName'])
    return "Checkbox is checked";
else 
    return "Checkbox is not checked";
```